# How to get Fields of the current class?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to get the fields of the current class. I make the class implement the `ICloneable` Interface.

Inside the `clone()` the following line doesn't seem to find any fields. Why though?

```
foreach (FieldInfo fi in this.GetType().GetFields())
{
}
```

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) as:

```
var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public;
foreach (FieldInfo fi in this.GetType().GetFields(flags))
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That will only find public fields. Look at `BindingFlags`.

To suggest a better way, just call `MemberwiseClone`, it will copy all the fields values in the current class/instance.

Answer (score 1):

Because only public fields are returned by default.  Use the other overload with `BindingFlags.NonPublic`.

Answer (score 0):

GetFields returns all the public fields of the current Type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3.aspx You may need http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well the only reason why GetFields would be empty is if "no public fields are defined for the current Type" (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3.aspx)).

More generally, did you know that there already exists a protected method in the Object class that already does what you're trying to do (a shallow copy)? It's called [MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx)

You could use it like this:

```
public object Clone()
{
    return MemberWiseClone();
}
```